# Why does my O(NLogN) algorithm to find anagrams run faster than my O(N) algorithm?

Tags: java, hashmap, runtime, big-o, anagram

I have a hashset of words that are all the same length. I want to find all of the anagrams that exist in this hashset and collect them into another hashset called anagrams. Here is the loop that does that:

```
public HashSet<String> getUniqueAnagramsSlow(HashSet<String> paddedWords, int areAnagramsVersion){
    HashSet<String> anagrams = new HashSet<String>(); 
    Object[] paddedWordsArr = paddedWords.toArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < paddedWordsArr.length-1; i++){
        boolean foundAnagram = false;
        String wordOne = (String) paddedWordsArr[i];
        if(!anagrams.contains(wordOne)) 
            for(int j = i+1; j < paddedWordsArr.length; j++){
                String wordTwo = (String) paddedWordsArr[j];
                if(areAnagrams(wordOne, wordTwo, areAnagramsVersion)){
                    foundAnagram = true;
                    anagrams.add(wordTwo);
                }
            }
        if(foundAnagram){
            anagrams.add(wordOne);
        }
    }
    return anagrams;
}
```

My goals in writing this code is to see how different areAnagram() functions can affect run time. I wrote two versions of areAnagrams(). One that sorts two strings and compares them and another that uses hashmaps to compare character frequency. Here they are:

```
public boolean areAnagramsVersionOne(String first, String second){
    char[] arr1 = first.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    String fSorted = new String( arr1 );
    char[] arr2 = second.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    String sSorted = new String(arr2);
    return fSorted.equals(sSorted);
}
public boolean areAnagramsVersionTwo(String first, String second){
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordOne = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++){
        String letOne = first.substring(i, i+1);
        if(wordOne.containsKey(letOne)){
            int letOneFreq = wordOne.get(letOne);
            wordOne.put(letOne, letOneFreq + 1);
        }else{
            wordOne.put(letOne, 1);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < second.length(); i++){
        String letTwo = second.substring(i, i+1);
        if(!wordOne.containsKey(letTwo))
            return false;
        int freq = wordOne.get(letTwo);
        if(freq == 0)
            return false;
        wordOne.put(letTwo, freq-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

From my understanding, areAnagramsVersionOne() will run in NlogN time and the areAnagramsVersionTwo() will run in N time. However, when I test these two versions of finding anagrams in my original loop, version two is is noticeably slower. Why is this?

Thank you.

This is an example of how I test run time:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
getUniqueAnagramsSlow(words, 2);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("exec time: " + (endTime - startTime) );
```

Comment: And how do you test it? Do you "warm up" the JVM before you start cycling ? or do you use a benchmark framework ?

Comment: How does the performance change with increasing N? Don't you need to check that the counts in the hashmap are 0 at the end of the second function?

Comment: @sje397 In my O(n) algorithm, I check to see if the count is 0 before I decrement the value in the hashmap. If it is 0, I return false because I know the second word has a character that does not exist in word one.

Comment: @ArjunPatel But if the first word has a character that is not in the second word, you may still return true, because you don't check that all the vaules in the Map are 0 at the end.

Comment: @Eran All of the words are the same length.

Comment: @ArjunPatel Oh, I see. That should work then.

Comment: @alfasin I edited my post to show you how I test the execution time. I also ran the function in a loop and the results were very consistent.

Comment: @ArjunPatel that's not how you check performance! read a bit about benchmarking in Java. This test is meaningless, like I wrote - the JVM needs a warmup and you should iterate at least a few thousands of cycles on each algorithm and only then compare. Look for micro-benchmark frameworks!

Comment: @alfasin Thanks, I will try that out and see how it goes. Is it still possible for my second version to run slower than my first version even after examining the benchmark results?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the input. For example, if your input causes the execution to return `false` most of the time for the following condition: `if(!anagrams.contains(wordOne))` then the first version will run ~n cycles while the second version always runs 2xn cycles.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know O(NlogN) is guaranteed to be greater than O(N) only for sufficiently large values of N, because at small values coefficients and constants that are not represented in O() notation are still relevant. Consider 2 algorithms such that their cost is:

Algorithm 1 cost: 100*N: O(N)

Algorithm 2 cost: 10*NlogN: O(NlogN)

O(NlogN) > O(N) => 10*NlogN > 100*N => 10*logN > 100 => logN > 10

So in this case algorithm 2 will cost more than algorithm 1 when N > 2^10. For smaller values, algorithm 2 will be less costly, even if it is "less efficient" according to O() notation.

Read [the wikipedia page for O() notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more details.

Comment: That's Theta(n). O(n) is just a bound on one side. n^3 is O(n^10) and n^4 is O(n^8).

Comment: @DouglasZare Thanks for the input. Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @Arjun Patel: Big-O and little-o notation means there is an upper bound. Theta means there are both upper and lower bounds. You can't say that an O(n) function must grow more slowly asymptotically than an O(n^2) function.